# Pass props when component use forwardRef typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-forwardref

I have an component AddComment with `forwardRef`:

```
function AddComment({ comment, setComment }: Props, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) {
  return (<div ref={ref}>
  // code...
  </div>)
}
export default forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>(AddComment)
```

In parent component:

```
function Parent() {
  const [comment, setComment] = useState('')
  const addCommentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

  return (<div>
  // code ...
    <AddComment ref={addCommentRef} comment={comment} setComment={setComment}/>
  </div>)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Argument of type '({ comment, setComment }: Props, ref: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLDivElement, {}>'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Props': comment, setComment
```

When I run on browser, it runs well, but I have the error in VS Code.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forwardRef` is a generic function that has type parameters for the type of the ref and the props.

change it to `forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, Props>(AddComment)` to include `Props` type.

read more on `forwardRef` in [this article](https://www.carlrippon.com/react-forwardref-typescript/)